# Completely delete all instances of a div with a specific class using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, removeclass

I am using Popup.js by Toddish.
http://docs.toddish.co.uk/popup/demos/

Long story short, the popup plugin creates divs by default given the classes ".popup_back" and ".popup_cont".
I have another button I wish to press which should completely delete the added divs with those classes after they have been generated and added to the html. As if they never even existed. Surely this is possible?

I have tried running a function which simply runs:

```
$(".popup_back").remove();
$(".popup_cont").remove();
```

As shown in this example:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_remove

Unfortunately despite the code running, the actual divs are never deleted as required.

Any ideas? I am new to this kind of thing and have googled around and read a lot about DOM etc but am yet to crack it.

Thanks

EDIT:
In reply to the comments:

The Javascript:

```
function removePopups() { // This function is called to remove the popups.
   console.log("removing...");
   $(".popup_back").remove();
   $(".popup_cont").remove();
}



function func(url) { // url is the url of the image to be displayed within the popup.
   removePopups(); // As soon as the function casillas is called, removePopups is used to remove any existing instances of the divs.

   $('a.theimage').popup({ // This is where the Popup plugin is utilised.
       content : $(url),
       type : 'html'
   });
}
```

The HTML:

```
<a class="theimage" onclick="func('image/image1.jpg')" href="#" >
```

Long story short, an image is displayed in the popup. 
I think the issue is that the popup plugin runs due to the class but the function func is never actually run when the click occurs. However simultaneously "removing..." still prints out in the console which tells me that the function IS being executed. The problem is I want the popup plugin to run together with the javascript function. Is there a solution for this conflict?

Comment: It should work, when/how are you calling those two lines?

Comment: Can you post a context for where you execute those lines. They should do exactly what you want, and there is a good chance you are just executing them at the wrong time.

Comment: It could just be that those DIVs don't exist at the time you are attempting to remove them. Can you post your markup?

Comment: I'll edit in to the main post my reply to you guys so that the code can be seen more clearly. Thanks!

Comment: Run your script after Popup.js cause this should work. In html add popup.js before your js. You can use Firebug on firefox which is a really nice and helpfull plugin to debug Javascript. It allows you like a normal debug to check what is in a variable and even make queries to a specific div or anything like in a normal javascript console.

Comment: Move your `removePopups()` call to AFTER the initialization of the popup.

Comment: The problem still persists I'm afraid Bic.

Comment: Haig, the divs definitely exist as far as I can see when inspecting the live page... particularly where I can physically see the popup on the page which is the div.

Comment: There is an `afterOpen` option for the extension. Have you tried running your `removePopups()` there?

Comment: Thanks Bic! That's got us one step closer. I'm now executing removePopups() using the beforeClose option. The problem now is that it only executes when the user exits the popup by clicking the small 'x' in the corner but doesn't when they just click away from the popup. I'll look in to it but we're definitely almost there! It also seems like there is a small delay when deleting the divs which is causing an issue. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: You need to bind your "remove" function to whatever button you are creating for this purpose. From the popup demo, the popups already close if you click the X or click on any part of the page so recreating this behavior seems redundant. If you need help with that, I can post an example.

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying Haig, the problem is that on my end the previous divs created are getting deleted simply when the popup is closed but re-appear as part of the next popup-. Therefore if the contents of the popup are changed, what happens is you get the new popup with the old contents & another popup on top with the new contents. Hence why I need to remove the older popup completely.

Comment: That's interesting. Something in your implementation must be causing this behavior because it doesn't happen on the demo. Do you see any errors in your console log? If there's a javascript error, it could be preventing further code execution. It's really hard to say what the problem might be from what you've posted, but if you're willing to post a working demo of your code on http://jsfiddle.net, it'll be easier to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Posted a solution to what I think is your problem below. Checking out for now.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation should really be as simple as this:

```
<a class="theimage" href="#" >Open</a>
```

Bind the popup creation to your popup link:

```
$('a.theimage').popup({
    content : 'image/image1.jpg',
    type : 'html'
});
```

I'm speculating here, but what might be happening is that you're invoking the popup twice by binding the popup() call to a click handler in your markup. The popup plugin already binds the popup creation to a click event.

View working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p5t7a9gu/). Note the 3 external resource: the popup CSS, the popup JS, and the jQuery JS.